# Where is BillingResponse.OK for the Android Billing Library

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library

When setting up a new in-app purchase flow for Android, the sample code on Google Developer website says to use the following snippet.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

```
if (result.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
   for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
       String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
       String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
       if ("premium_upgrade".equals(sku)) {
           premiumUpgradePrice = price;
       } else if ("gas".equals(sku)) {
           gasPrice = price;
       }
   }
}
```

However, `BillingResponse.OK` doesn't exist. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a refactor has changed where this response code lives. Try using this instead:

```
if (result.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
        String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
        String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
        if ("premium_upgrade".equals(sku)) {
            premiumUpgradePrice = price;
        } else if ("gas".equals(sku)) {
            gasPrice = price;
        }
    }
}
```

The BillingResponseCode.OK now lives here in the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse#OK